# turning css class into mixin

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, mixins, saas

Below is my css code.

```
div {
 &:before {
    position: absolute;
    width: 48%;
    height: 10px;
    content: ' ';
    left: 20px;
    bottom: 40px;
    @include vendor(transform, top);
    @include vendor(transform, skew(-5deg) rotate(-3deg));
    @include vendor(box-shadow, 0 30px 4px 10px red);
    z-index: -1;
  }
}
```

Below is my mixin.

```
@mixin prefix($property, $value) {
  -webkit-#{$property}: $value;
  -moz-#{$property}: $value;
  -ms-#{$property}: $value;
  -o-#{$property}: $value;
  #{$property}: $value;
}
```

Is it possible to turn the entire before block code into a generic `mixin` like `add-effect`.

Answer (score 2):

```
@mixin add-effect {
 &:before {
    position: absolute;
    width: 48%;
    height: 10px;
    content: ' ';
    left: 20px;
    bottom: 40px;
    @include vendor(transform, top);
    @include vendor(transform, skew(-5deg) rotate(-3deg));
    @include vendor(box-shadow, 0 30px 4px 10px red);
    z-index: -1;
  }
}
```